# Sonarqube No language plugin error when upgraded from 6.0 to 6.4

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I upgraded sonarqube from 6.0 to 6.4 on Jenkins

Sonar analysis was working fine with 6.0 but after the upgrade I got an error saying: **No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed**

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice when SonarQube is installed, some bundled plugins are automatically installed, see whcih plugins are installed automatically and maybe need to be upgraded.

There's an [upgrade](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) instructions,

When upgrading you need to install the plugins you use see [plugin versions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix)

SonarQube plugin to [jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin) dependencies:

> maven-plugin (version:2.14, optional)
>   workflow-cps (version:2.25, optional)
>   configurationslicing (version:1.40, optional)
>   jquery (version:1.11.2-0)

Comment: I saw this but I never installed any of the plugins ever for sonarqube 6.0 on Jenkins that are mentioned in  https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix

Comment: When SQ is installed, some bundled plugins are automatically installed for convenience. see what plugins are installed automatically

Comment: Just verified it...There was no plugin installed. I installed SonarJava plugin and restarted the server. Do i need other plugins as well? My aim is to scan just java code.

Comment: well it started working immediately after i installed SonarJava plugin.

Thanks